# Git reference repository for submodules

Tags: git, continuous-integration

With Git, it's possible to have a cache repository to reduce bandwidth requirements for CI usecases as indicated here: https://randyfay.com/content/reference-cache-repositories-speed-clones-git-clone-reference

Is it possible to do such a thing but for submodules as well? I'm not even sure what the interface to that would look like but I thought I'd ask anyway.

Comment: `cd dir/with/submodule ; git pull --reference the_reference .` ?

Comment: that would represent an annoying imperative solution which would also deviate from the standard recursive clone approach for nested repos. You're right though, it's better than nothing. Thanks

Comment: Also `git submodule foreach 'git pull --reference the_reference/$name'`

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a direct answer to the question but is an answer for one of the main motivations for the question.

I see that within Jenkins, this situation can be handled by a bare repo containing fetched content from multiple repos - within `Advanced sub-modules behaviours`:

```
Specify a folder containing a repository that will be used by Git as a reference during clone operations.
This option will be ignored if the folder is not available on the master or agent where the clone is being executed.
To prepare a reference folder with multiple subprojects, create a bare git repository and add all the remote urls then perform a fetch:


git init --bare
git remote add SubProject1 https://gitrepo.com/subproject1
git remote add SubProject2 https://gitrepo.com/subproject2
git fetch --all
```